# Update div when writing text does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to write content in a `textarea` and display exactly what I am writing without have to refresh the page each letter that I type shows immediately well it is not working for some reason.

HTML:

```
 <textarea id="Q&A" name="txtarea" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
 <div id="out"></div>
```

Js:

```
function generate() {
  var reader = new commonmark.Parser();
  var writer = new commonmark.HtmlRenderer();
  var parsed = reader.parse(text);
  text = writer.render();
  document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = text
}

document.getElementById("Q&A").addEventListener("input", function () {
    generate(this.value);
});
```

When I try to update the div with the id of `out` to what I am typing using JavaScript, it does not work.

Comment: what is `commonmark` ?

Comment: Are you sure input is the correct event?  I would use keypress or some other events.  But this event handling complicates as you type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the `commonmark.Parser()` does in your code. But the issue i see is, When you are calling the `generate` method, you are passing the value of the input field. But in your generate method signature, you don't have a parameter to accept that.

Add a parameter to your `generate()` method to accept the value passed in.

```
function generate(text) {
   //do something else on text with your commonmark
   document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = text;
}
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/nujuqa/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample.

and you forgot to pass the argument `parsed` to the render function:

You had: `text = writer.render();` I changed it to `text = writer.render(parsed);`

Comment: thanks that helped i upvoted your answer please upvote mine

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out i forgot to have text pasted in as a argument  in the generate function and I forgot to pas parsed into the render function

Here is the final code:

```
function generate(text) {
  var reader = new commonmark.Parser();
  var writer = new commonmark.HtmlRenderer();
  var parsed = reader.parse(text);
  text = writer.render(parsed);
  document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = text
}

document.getElementById("Q&A").addEventListener("input", function () {
    generate(this.value);
});
```